# Mockito isA() & any...()

Tags: mockito

What is the difference between:

```
verify(mock, times(1)).myMethod(Matchers.isA(String.class));
verify(mock, times(1)).myMethod(Matchers.anyString());
```

from the Mockito library? Both pass for my method and I'm wondering which one is "better" to use.

Comment: btw, `times(1)` is the default and can be left off

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`isA`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html#isA(java.lang.Class)) checks that the class matches the expected class. In Mockito 1.x, `any`, `anyObject`, and [`anyString`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html#anyString()) ignore the argument entirely including its type, even though `any` can take a class parameter and `anyString` specifies it in the name.

Typically, unless you have a reason to guard against an incompatible argument being passed in, you can probably stick with `any` and `anyString`. Mockito style prefers flexible test cases, which means verifying only the things that you are explicitly checking, and deliberately allowing everything else to be unspecified.

**UPDATE:** Mockito committer [Brice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48136/brice) has offered [some historical background and future direction](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/55631479):

> For historical reference, `any` is a shorthand alias of `anything`, at that time the API was forcing one to cast, and contributors and/or commiters thought about passing the class as a param to avoid this cast, without changing the semantic of this API. However this change eventually modified what people thought that this API was doing. **This will be fixed in mockito 2+**

Comment: Then, for the latest version at least, we should use `any()` instead of `isA()`? Is that true?

Comment: @Robert I would avoid using `any(Clazz.class)` or `anyString()` etc due to the ambiguity. If you truly don't care about the value, use `any()`, and if you need it to be a certain type use `isA(Clazz.class)`. (If you're still compiling with Java 7, you may need to be pragmatic, but should probably upgrade instead.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, perfect explanations. But as far as I see, generally I do not need to check the value and maybe we could generally prefer using any().

Comment: On the other hand, sometimes I use a created variable of `Clazz` e.g. `clazz`, in this case can we say that I can also pass this `clazz` instead of `any(Clazz.class)` ?

Comment: @Robert Yes, Mockito style is to check as little as possible for maximum test flexibility, so in that sense `any()` is preferred. That said, `isA` is reasonable, and easily accepts any instance of type Class including your `clazz` variable, though depending on your specific example you may have to cast the value or strip the generics for Java to accept your `isA(clazz)` parameter.