# Mockito when() doesn't differentiate between child classes

Tags: java, mockito, apache-httpcomponents

I wrote a test that uses Mockito 1.9.5. I have an [HttpGet](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) and an [HttpPost](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) which an [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient.html) execute, and I'm testing to verify that the response from each returns the expected result in the form of an input stream.

The issue is that while using 
`Mockito.when(mockedClient.execute(any(HttpPost.class))).thenReturn(postResponse)` and `Mockito.when(mockedClient.execute(any(HttpGet.class))).thenReturn(getResponse)`, where the responses are different objects, `mockedClient.execute()` always returns `getResponse`.

The test I've written is below:

```
private InputStream       postContent;
private InputStream       getContent;
@Mock
private FilesHandler hand;
@Mock
private MockHttpClient    client;
private MockHttpEntity    postEntity;
private MockHttpEntity    getEntity;
private MockHttpResponse  postResponse;
private MockHttpResponse  getResponse;
private String imgQuery = "someQuery";
private ParametersHandler ph;
private FileHandlerImpl   fileHand;
private String            indexFolder = "src/test/resources/misc/";
private String            indexFile   = "index.csv";

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    try {
        postContent = new FileInputStream(indexFolder + "testContent.txt");
        postEntity = new MockHttpEntity(postContent);
        postResponse = new MockHttpResponse(postEntity, new BasicStatusLine(new ProtocolVersion("http", 1, 1), 200, "postReasonPhrase"));
        getContent = new FileInputStream(indexFolder + "testContent.txt");
        getEntity = new MockHttpEntity(getContent);
        getResponse = new MockHttpResponse(getEntity, new BasicStatusLine(new ProtocolVersion("http", 1, 1), 200, "getReasonPhrase"));
        ph = new ParametersHandler();
        fileHand = new FileHandlerImpl(client, ph, indexFolder, indexFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        failTest(e);
    }
}
@Test
public void getFileWhenEverythingJustWorks() {

    try {
        Mockito.when(client.execute(Mockito.any(HttpPost.class))).thenReturn(postResponse);
        Mockito.when(client.execute(Mockito.any(HttpGet.class))).thenReturn(getResponse);
        fileHand.getFile(hand, imgQuery, ph, "I");
        Mockito.verify(hand).rebuildIndex(Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(Map.class), Mockito.any(Map.class), hand);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        failTest(e);
    }
}
```

A shortened version of the method being tested is below.

```
public void getFile(FilesHandler fileHandlerFl, String query, ParametersHandler ph, String type) {

        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        HttpPost post = preparePost(query, factory);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    String uri = "https://someuri.com" + "/File";
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
        setParameters(get);
        response.close();
        response = client.execute(get);
}
```

As always, any help you can provide is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite what it would mean when read in English, in Mockito 1.x, [`any(HttpGet.class)` matches *any value* and not just *any HttpGet*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21430378/1426891). The parameter is only used to save a cast previous to Java 8.

From the [Matchers.any(Class) documentation](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html#any(java.lang.Class)):

> Matches any object, including nulls
>
> This method doesn't do type checks with the given parameter, it is only there to avoid casting in your code. This might however change (type checks could be added) in a future major release.

Use `isA(HttpGet.class)` and `isA(HttpPost.class)` instead, and see Brice's comment below about future changes to the `any(Class<?> clazz)` matcher.

Comment: For historical reference, `any` is a shorthand alias of `anything`, at that time the API was forcing one to cast, and contributors and/or commiters thought about passing the class as a param to avoid this cast, without changing the semantic of this API. However this change eventually modified what people thought that this API was doing. **This will be fixed in mockito 2+**

Comment: @Brice Thanks for the information! Updating this answer and a few others on SO.

Comment: I know this is several years old now but we recently ran into a similar problem. Another solution that worked for us was to chain `thenReturn` calls, knowing the order in which the calls were made. 

For example, 

`when (httpClient.execute(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(getResponse).thenReturn(putResponse);`

I like the `isA` as a better solution but thought I'd add the one we found that worked as well.