# Mockito and Mockito.any(Map.class)

Tags: hashmap, mockito

Using Mockito I got in trouble with the following:

```
Mockito.when(restOperationMock.exchange(
      Mockito.anyString(),     
      Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class),
      Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class),  
      Mockito.eq(CustomerResponse.class),
      **Mockito.anyMap()**)).
    thenReturn(re);
```

The problem was the method wasn't intercepted because I was using `Mockito.any(Map.class)` instead of `Mockito.anyMap()` and I was passing as a parameter a `HashMap`. What are the differences between `Mockito.any(Map.class)` and  `Mockito.anyMap()`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is only one small difference between `any(Map.class)` and `anyMap()`: **Starting with Mockito 2.0**, Mockito will treat the `any(Map.class)` call to mean `isA(Map.class)` rather than ignoring the parameter entirely. (See the comment from Mockito contributor Brice on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33904939/1426891).) Because [`restOperationMock.exchange` takes an Object vararg](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-), you may need `anyMap` to catch a case where a non-Map object is being passed, or no object at all is passed.

(I'd previously put that as a "dummy value" to return, Mockito can return an empty Map for calls to `anyMap()`, but can only return a `null` for calls to `any(Map.class)`. If `restOperationMock.exchange` delegates to a real implementation during stubbing, such as if it were a spy or unmockable method (final method, method on a final class, etc), then that dummy value may be used in real code. However, that's only true for `any()`; `anyMap()` and `any(Map.class)` both give Mockito enough information to return a dummy Map implementation, where `any()` has its generics erased and only knows enough to return `null`.)