# ArgumentMatchers.any() versus the other matchers in Mockito 2

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

With Mockito 2, should `ArgumentMarchers.any()` be used instead of more specific matchers like `ArgumentMatchers.anyString()` or `ArgumentMatchers.anyList()` for example? Should specific matchers be used to make the code more readable?

From experience, when using native objets (`int`, `long`, `double`, `boolean`), specific matchers `anyInt()`, `anyLong()`, `anyDouble()` or `anyBoolean()` is preferred. But what about the other matchers? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In short, you could use either one in most cases (especially in Java 8 or newer). `any()` is often more idiomatic to non-brittle Mockito tests, though there are some pragmatic reasons and some correctness reasons to use `anyString` or `any(String.class)`. Beware: the full rationale delves deeply into Mockito matcher internals, Java type parameter inference, and a whole lot of [hysterical raisins](http://catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html).

---

For primitives like `anyFloat()`, there is a very practical reason to prefer `anyFloat()` etc instead of `any()`: The latter will give you a NullPointerException. For Mockito syntax like `when(floatAcceptor.acceptFloat(any())).then(/*...*/)`, Mockito will actually call your mocked `floatAcceptor.acceptFloat(float)` method, and calls to `any()` necessarily return `null` [because Mockito matchers have to return a dummy value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822514/1426891) and Java doesn't tell Mockito enough for it to know to return a `float`-compatible value. Irrespective of Mockito, Java will try to unbox a `null` into a `float` and fail.
 (`anyFloat()` and `any(Float.class)` [tell Mockito to expect a `float`](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/util/Primitives.java#L53), so they correctly return `0.0f`.) **If you know a value is a primitive, boxed or unboxed, it's safer to call the appropriate method.** 
That reason goes away for `List` and `String`, which are objects through and through; Java will happily pass a `null` received from `any`.

Historically, `any` behaved identically to `any(Class)`, `anyString()`, and `anyList(Class)`; this was an important convenience, because Java 7 couldn't infer type arguments from parameters, so the alternative was `(Foo) any()` or `ArgumentMatchers.<Foo>any()`. Compared to those, `any(Foo.class)` is more readable. It gets even worse for Lists, because type literals don't support other types, so `any(List.class)` won't even work for `List<Bar>`; you'd need `(List<Bar>) any()`, or `ArgumentMatchers.<List<Bar>>any()`, but with `anyList` you can just write `anyList(Bar.class)` and be on your way. In all cases, the argument was entirely ignored, and to check types you'd need to use `isA(Class)` to do a reflective, `null`-rejecting, `instanceof`-style check.

However, two improvements happened that change this: [Java 8 happily infers type arguments through parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38092697/1426891), so `any()` is much more usable, and [Mockito corrected its syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904877/mockito-when-doesnt-differentiate-between-child-classes/33904939#comment55631479_33904939) to appear more like English. In English, "any car" wouldn't likely include a bicycle or an empty parking spot, but in Mockito 1.x `any(Car.class)` would happily match invocations with a `null` or a `Bicycle` instance. Thus, in Mockito 2.x, `any(String)` and `anyString()` will only accept non-`null` Strings, [as documented in GitHub issue #185](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/185#issuecomment-85430147). Same with all other `any(Class)` calls.

To top it all off, Mockito prefers flexible tests rather than brittle ones, so you are much more likely to see `any()` for an irrelevant `Foo` parameter than `isA(Foo.class)` or `eq(new Foo())`. Irrelevant parameters are ignored by convention, if changing them is unlikely to affect the behavior being tested. That said, `anyString()` and `anyList()` can be useful for readability when you know the argument isn't `null`, and can also help you keep track of long argument lists by failing to compile if your list changes in an incompatible way to the method you're calling.

**So in summary:** Use primitive methods for primitives, use `any()` as much as possible, but switch to `any(Class)`, `any(List)`, or `any(String)` if you want to check non-`null` types are correct, if you want to improve readability, or you need to maintain long frequently-changing argument lists.

You can read more on the semantics of `any()`, `any(Class)`, and `isA` on [this GitHub issues answer](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/185#issuecomment-85430147).